# python - is it possible to compare the list between 2 lists using the specific digit?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary, compare

I am a new student who is learning to programme with python and I have 2 example lists which are

```
selected_ipc = ['H01L']
df = [[ 'F24J3/02 ', 'A123'], [ 'G01N31/10 ', 'A124'], [ 'H01L27/14 ', 'A125'], ['G21H1/10 ', 'A126'], ['H01L21/36 ', 'A127']]
```

I have created a simple code like this

```
for item in selected_ipc:
    for item1 in df:
        if item == item1:
            print (item)
        else:
            print("No match")
```

and the results are returned 'No match' while my expected result is

```
[[ 'H01L27/14 ', 'A125'], ['H01L21/36 ', 'A127']]
```

therefore, I would like to ask is it possible to compare the first list with the first 4 digits in the second list?

thank you in advance

Comment: Question says compare with *first 4 digits* so probably want to use `string.startswith` method, not `in`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [startswith](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith):

```
selected_ipc = ['H01L']
df = ['F24J3/02 ', 'G01N31/10 ', 'H01L27/14 ', 'G21H1/10 ', 'H01L21/36 ']

for item in selected_ipc:
    for item1 in df:
        if item1.startswith(item):
            print(item1)
        else:
            print("No match")
```

**Output**

```
No match
No match
H01L27/14 
No match
H01L21/36
```

**UPDATE**

For a nested list you could use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
selected_ipc = ['H01L']
df = [['F24J3/02 ', 'A123'], ['G01N31/10 ', 'A124'], ['H01L27/14 ', 'A125'], ['G21H1/10 ', 'A126'],
      ['H01L21/36 ', 'A127']]

result = [lst for lst in df if any(lst[0].startswith(e) for e in selected_ipc)]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[['H01L27/14 ', 'A125'], ['H01L21/36 ', 'A127']]
```

As an alternative you could use a less *pythonic* way with two loops:

```
selected_ipc = ['H01L']
df = [['F24J3/02 ', 'A123'], ['G01N31/10 ', 'A124'], ['H01L27/14 ', 'A125'], ['G21H1/10 ', 'A126'],
      ['H01L21/36 ', 'A127']]

result = []
for lst in df:
    found = False
    for e in selected_ipc:
        if lst[0].startswith(e):
            found = True
            result.append(lst)
            break
    if not found:
        print("No match")

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
No match
No match
No match
[['H01L27/14 ', 'A125'], ['H01L21/36 ', 'A127']]
```

Comment: @Sungjin I updated my answer to include nested lists

Answer (score 0):

```
selected_ipc = ['H01L']
df = ['F24J3/02 ', 'G01N31/10 ', 'H01L27/14 ', 'G21H1/10 ', 'H01L21/36 ']
l = []
for i in df:
   if selected_ipc[0] in i:
       l.append(i)
print l
```

Comment: please provide an explanation to improve the quality of your answer :)

Comment: i have edited the post, because i wonder when the nested list occurred, why the result are []

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with list comprehensions like below

```
selected_ipc = ['H01L']
df = ['F24J3/02 ', 'G01N31/10 ', 'H01L27/14 ', 'G21H1/10 ', 'H01L21/36 ']

for item in selected_ipc:
    match_lst = [item1 for item1 in df if item in item1]

print(match_lst)
```

**UPDATE**

If you want check for the other elements(instead of first one) of the lists in list "df" then you can checkout the below code

```
selected_ipc = ['H01L', 'G01N', 'A126']
df = [['F24J3/02 ', 'A123'], ['G01N31/10 ', 'A124'], ['H01L27/14 ', 'A125'], ['G21H1/10 ', 'A126'],
      ['H01L21/36 ', 'A127']]

match_lst = [item1 for item1 in df if any(i.startswith(item) for item in selected_ipc for i in item1)]
print(match_lst)
```

**Output**

```
[['G01N31/10 ', 'A124'], ['H01L27/14 ', 'A125'], ['G21H1/10 ', 'A126'], ['H01L21/36 ', 'A127']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension check if the key is in the item if so add it to your list

```
res = [i for i in df if selected_ipc[0] in i[0]]
# [['H01L27/14 ', 'A125'], ['H01L21/36 ', 'A127']]
```